# How to escape single & double quotes in MySQL select?

Tags: mysql, sql

`select name from movies where id = 1;` gives me

```
name
----------
How the 'A' Stole Christmas
```

How would I select in order to get

```
name
----------
How the \'A\' Stole Christmas
```

I can use `replace(title,'\'','\\\'')` which turns ugly since I need to do it twice one for single & double quote, Curious to know if there is cleaner approach

Comment: See PHP's function [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) that "*returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped*".

Comment: What does PHP have to do here? This is not for server side programming but data processing.

Comment: I indeed now notice that PHP wasn't tagged for this question. My bad.

Comment: No Worries, The reason I asked this I will be using the output to construct other SQL statements which will be executed in different environment.

Comment: Write a function to escape special characters so that your query will not look ugly.

Comment: It' turns out the good idea far.

Answer (score 2):

Struggling with escaping characters is a sign that you may be unnecessarily converting strings manually as data flows through different systems. The question I would ask is whether it is necessary to have escaped strings for your requirements.

When constructing and executing your queries you should use bind variables which removes the need to quote strings to build up your Sql queries and minimizes the risk of Sql injection security issues.

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Once you have Sql results in a variable or PHP structure it is often better to find functions/libraries such as JSON functions described at https://coderwall.com/p/p2kumg/json_encode-vs-serialize-with-php-arrays

And of course there's http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp as mentioned by D4V1D as a comment.

Edit ...
There also appears to be a Mysql QUOTE() function that does what you are asking.

See http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-quote-function.php

Comment: Thanks for the write, However the question has nothing to with PHP. May be you can leave the answer for future php Googlers.

Comment: my apologies - such a common PHP problem that I failed to notice it not. It would be useful to have a more complete use case with the problem to provide the context of examining the point in which quotes are causing problems. I am just reluctant to look at escaping results without knowing whether this could be done at some other point along the data flow.

Comment: This shows how powerful and popular the PHP kingdom is :p

Comment: The thinking behind this is valid though - most mysql and other DB drivers will provide support for bind variables and these are what should be used rather than dancing with escaping and unescaping wherever possible.

Comment: Good intention but bad guess since you have assumed that I am doing server side programming, while I'm not.

Comment: Again apols and thanks for the clarification although I remain confused as to how you can perform sql queries to obtain data used to generate sql on a different system without using something server side? If you have control of the serving MySql server you may get some joy be configuring NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes although this would appear to do the opposite of what is required - looks like the string replacement may be the only option

Comment: Also worth looking at the QUOTE function SELECT QUOTE('w3re''source');